# Make datetime update automatically

Tags: python

Is it possible for datetime to be updated as the program is running? My discord bot will be running 24/7

Code I have

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
file.write(redeemkey + " // Discord ID: " + authorID + " - IP: " + response['ipAddress'] + " - Redemed at: " + now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + "\n")
```

But that just writes the time that the bot was started and not when the command was actually called

Comment: datetime.now() always returns the current date and does not depend on when the program was started, so the issue is not that.

Answer (score 1):

I put my `now = datetime.datetime.now()` inside an if statement that gets called when the command is called (`!redeem`). That overrides it